# find valid words in randomly generated characters in c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have generated random characters at runtime and after generating I need to know the count of valid words formed with the listed characters. And that is not in a matrix form, it will show in a single line.

This is the code for generating random characters:

```
  public void  GenerateLettersAtStart()
 {
 for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
    wordRan.wordsStore.Clear();
    a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,consonants.Length);
    availablesetConsonants [i].GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text  = 
   consonants[a].ToString();
   }
   for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
    {
    wordRan.wordsStore.Clear();
    b = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, vowels.Length);
    availablesetVowels [j].GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = 
   vowels[b].ToString();
    }
   }
```

its literally like permutations but the word should be meaningful. i have text document to compare i have load that through text asset.. it is a word scrambler game actually here i need to show the count of unscrambled valid words from the listed random letters –

```
void Awake() { string[] w = wordAsset.text.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' 
    }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); allWords = new 
    HashSet(w);

    }
  public void Start()
   {
  //RepeatedWordsCheck ();    
   }
    public void Update()
   {

    }

  public bool CheckWord(string wrd)
  {
  return allWords.Contains(wrd.ToLower());

   }
  public void ClickFun() 
   {
  Debug.Log ("acx");
  bool Check = CheckWord (GameController.currentWord);
  if (Check == true  )
  {
  Debug.Log("correct word");
  }
     }
```

Comment: You need to explain more what's the problem with the code. (what's the current/expected output?)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder letters in each real word in alphabetical order, eg. word "cat" will change to "act". Having such a dictionary you can sort randomly generated characters in same order and then you can just match strings by == operator.

Comment: i have 10 random letters so have to check all possible combinations (2letter valid word, 3letter valid word,4letter valid word,5 letter valid word , upto 10 ketter valid word)

Comment: Oh, I see - you have not to use all letters from randomly generated set. So you can check if real word is patten matching to generated set, eg. for "cat"->"act" you have to check if Regex(@"\w*a\w*c\w*t\w*").Matches("aaabbccckkkoottzzz")  (\w* means any number of word characters)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem. The issue (as you probably guessed) is that basic brute force solution might be extremely slow (checking many combinations).

Here is how I would do it:

Make a list of pairs:

```
var listOfPairs = new List<KeyValuePair>();
```

each word is saved as a pair like this:

> {{word, word}, {fork, fork}, {other, other}, ...}

now for each pair, compare it with all your random letter. So if you have N words in the dictionary and 10 random letters, this will be done in max 10*N operation (complexity O(N), which is rather good)

Each time you compare a word with a letter, remove the letter from the first element of the pair: Lets take an example: you test the word `word`:

> {word, word}

if the first random letter is `o`, you end up with

> {wrd, word}

if the second random letter is `a`, you end up with

> {wrd, word}

if the second random letter is `d`, you end up with

> {wr, word}

And so on. To this for all words in your dictionary.

At the end, all the pairs in the list with the first element being an empty string can be written with your random letters.

You can retrieve this using a for loop checking for empty keys, or using Linq:

```
var listOfPairs = new List<KeyValuePair>();

// Do the algorithm described above

// Retrieve words that can be written with the random letters
possibleWords = listOfPairs.Where(pair => pair.key == "").Select(pair => pair.value)
```

---

By the way, you could choose a random number of vowels in the generation code, to vary even more the possibilities:

```
public void  GenerateLettersAtStart()
{
    int nbVowels = (int)Random.Range(2, 5);
    int nbConsonants = 10-nbVowels;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbConsonants; i++)
    {
        wordRan.wordsStore.Clear();
        a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,consonants.Length);
        availablesetConsonants [i].GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text  = 
        consonants[a].ToString();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nbVowels; j++)
    {
        wordRan.wordsStore.Clear();
        b = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, vowels.Length);
        availablesetVowels [j].GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = 
       vowels[b].ToString();
    }
}
```